# Using Moq, do I always need to mock all dependencies?

Tags: unit-testing, dependency-injection, refactoring, mocking, moq

I had the following line in over 100 of my tests:

```
var registry = new Mock<ObjectRegistry>(new List<Assembly>()).Object;
```

A little refactoring changed my ObjectRegistry constructor to:

```
public ObjectRegistry(AssemblyRegistry assemblies, UserPromt userPromt)
```

So I have to update all my 100 Testcases to use the following mock instead:

```
var objectRegistry = new Mock<ObjectRegistry>(Mock.Of<AssemblyRegistry>(), Mock.Of<UserPromt>());
```

And all I want is that all dependencies are mocked, invariant no matter what dependencies I need.

Can I tell Moq somehow to mock all dependencies it needs automatically?

In java with Mockito this would not be an issue at all ...

Comment: Why are they in hundred lines of tests? Couldn't that have been in a `SetUp`?

Comment: Apply the same sort of code smell detection to your tests as to your code, DRY. If you find yourself repeating the same code, refactor to a method.

Comment: I figured out, that in many cases the mock was already in the setup. ... So you are right, that helped already.

Answer (score 3):

You are mocking a concrete object here. Moq works best when used with an interface. Try to [mock roles, not objects](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDQQFjAA&url=http://jmock.org/oopsla2004.pdf&ei=mQUpUb_1IbKN0wXqloHIBA&usg=AFQjCNG1hoMD7NunoONsaOmVDgaQYkNmFA&sig2=7bAySxnUn5GMNBCs12mjBg&bvm=bv.42768644,d.d2k) (pdf). For example, introduce an interface such as `IObjectRegistry`. At present your code knows it is dealing with an ObjectRegistry, when ideally you should be able to switch your implementation out whenever you wish. Providing you have an abstraction in place. It would be ideal both for testability and programming best practices to "*program to an interface*" instead. Note interface here does not necessarily mean an interface in terms of C#/Java etc.

```
var registry = new Mock<IObjectRegistry>();

public class ObjectRegistry : IObjectRegistry { // Snip }
```

Then use this. As this is an interface, you can freely change the concrete (real/production) class and its constructor as you wish. Your tests and the rest of the system should be unaware. If the registry had one method on the interface such as `GetObject` your system should simply rely on this abstraction, not the fact it is working with an `ObjectRegistry` instance.

Currently your code is actually creating a real instance of an `ObjectRegistry`, then stubbing/mocking the methods in question. This is not ideal in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

The best practice for your problem is to use Interfaces instead of concrete classes and pass your dependencies by those interfaces.

`public ObjectRegistry(IAssemblyRegistry assemblies, IUserPromt userPromt)`

Comment: Using dependency injection in your unit tests is not a good idea. All the dependencies of your system under test should be mocked. If you are using DI in your unit test you are actually creating integration tests.

Comment: Yea I made bad experience with DI in Tests my self. But if you build a fresh container for every testcalss it can work out well.  - Still I'm not going to do this if I do not have to.

Comment: I don't see the sense to pollute my clean code with a whole new layer of interfaces. People seem to like Interfaces but there are reasons do use them, test compatibility should not be a reason.

Comment: @Tarion programming to an interface is "a good thing". The fact you can switch out dependencies to make testability easier is a bonus.

Comment: @WouterdeKort you seem to be confused on what DI actually is. Using a DI/IOC container in your unit tests is a bad thing yeah, but DI (the act of passing in the classes dependencies via a constructor/method) is the right thing to do.

Comment: @Finglas Your right of course.. I meant the use of a DI Container, not DI itself.